# jquery not working in symfony 3.3 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, twig

i have a jequery script to handle converting a youtube video url (the url is a value of field of the entity "Cours")  to embed code. Unfortunately this script is not working

```
YouTube ID: <span id="myId"></span>
<br />
<br />
Embed code: <pre id="myCode"></pre>      

               {{ cours.description }}
               {{ cours.prerequis }}  



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">


     function getId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
        return match[2];
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}

var myId = getId('{{ cours.videoIntro }}');

$('#myId').html(myId);

$('#myCode').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + myId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');        

</script>
```

Comment: <script  " src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"> that line is invalid... likely has an effect...

Comment: i updated the question and changed this line to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: *this script is not working* Please describe the problem or copy the error message. And please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Have you  check with the script link, maybe use CDN like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i updated my question. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work

Comment: then we need to know why it's error. Please copy the error message, we might answer it.